# How to populate WinForm field with SQL query based on inherited parameter from prior Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

My first form is one that allows the searching and finding of a person using a ComboBox: very simple. Once this person is selected (this is a concatenated value in the following format [lastname, firstname MI : Status : CustomerID]), it creates a new Form, where I'm wanting to take that "inherited" value (forgive me if I'm not using the term correctly) and populate various fields, such as DOB, address, etc.

What I'm wanting to do is use the customerID from the previous selection in a new SQL query to populate the fields on this new Form (use customerid from initial selection to find metadata like DOB, address, etc.). My current template for facilitating this field-to-be-populated uses a ListView. Should I be using something else that will do nothing but display a read-only SQL value?

Here's my form, to see clearly my intention:
[new form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGnZV.png)

Here is my code:

```
public partial class pract_info : Form
    {
        public pract_info()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Address_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have seen numerous examples of how to connect to SQL, but where I'm struggling is how they can all vary so greatly. Even if someone could provide a link that succinctly explains how it works, that would be amazing.

I am still learning C#, so my apologies if I'm asking questions that someone should feel I should already know. I'm trying to learn it, but I learn best by doing and seeing examples to visualize the concept in my head.

---

***Update 1:** I believe I understand where you are going Ashkan. Here is what I had in my main form prior to posting for help here:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

            pract_info form = new pract_info();
            form.Text = senderComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You can create a public property and set it when creating a new instance:

```
public partial class pract_info : Form
    {

        public int Id {get; set;}
        public pract_info()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Address_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

And in your main form:

```
pract_info frm = new pract_info ();
frm.Id = 123; 
frm.Show();
```

2.You may also change the new form Initializer to accept a parameter:

```
public partial class pract_info : Form
    {

        private int id;
        public pract_info(int Id)
        {
            id = Id;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Address_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

and then in your main form:

```
pract_info frm = new pract_info (123);
frm.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! When I implement this code, I get a couple of errors:
CS0103 The name 'id' does not exist in the current context
CS1729 'pract_info' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

I really have no idea what these mean. Lastly, when you say 'main form', I am interpreting that by selecting Program.cs under the section labeled 'static void Main()' Am I in the right spot? 

Thank you again, I really appreciate the input!

Comment: 1. by main form, i mean the form that your combobox exist and you want to open the second form from it. 2.you should either use solution (1) or (2) not both of them. 3.if it says `The name 'id' does not exist in the current context` it means that you have gone with solution 2, but you may have forgotton to add the line `private int id;` (the line before cunstructor in the solution)

Comment: replace `pract_info frm = new pract_info (123);
frm.Show();` with the code you were using to open the second form (of course change `123` to match the id variable you want to send)

Comment: I made an update in my original post, towards bottom under Update 1. Thank you!

Comment: the part in you form is correct, however `Form` already has a text property, change it to something like `CustomerId` or `Id` like: pract_info form = new pract_info();
form.CustomerId = senderComboBox.SelectedIndex
form.ShowDialog();`, and also note that you can just pass senderComboBox.SelectedIndex as it is already and integer. second thing you have to do is to create a public property in your `pract_info` form like: `public string CustomerId {get; set;}`

Comment: Ok, I understand that you are saying to pass the value on from the combobox, but it sounds like you are suggesting to pass the same value from the first Form to the second Form. What I need to do is use that value from the first Form in the WHERE clause of a SQL query to populate the different fields in the second Form. Apologies if I misunderstood you.

Comment: ok, I had misunderstood, then send the selecteditem.tostring and also, in your second form make the property to match the type: `public string CustomerId{get;set;}`

Comment: and please mark as answer if it solves your problem